# How to get concrete link to Build Log in Cruise Control Net?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

When I use [email] CC.Net task, received mail contains the link "http://**/ccnet/server/local/project/MyProjectName/ViewLatestBuildReport.aspx".
This link is to the "Last" report. If after that my project was rebuild this link will be incorrect.
Is there any standard solution to get concrete related Build Log link?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want to link to an old build?  It seems to me that you would only be concerned with the latest build.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a bit of work. During your build, form the link you need and write it to an xml file. Configure CC.net to merge this xml file into the log. Edit the CC.net header.xsl file to transform the link from xml to html as a new row. Then it will show up in the emails.